# pg_ctl: directory "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data" does not exist The reload command returned an error (1)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.2

When I try to open "*pg_hba.conf*" file, keep getting the following error:

> pg_ctl: directory "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data" does not exist
> The reload command returned an error (1)

How to get the access to
"*pg_hba.conf*" file if "*C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data*" folder is not present in path?

Comment: I guess you didn't use the `-D` option with the correct data directory as argument.

Comment: 1) Not sure what `pg_ctl`  has to do with accessing `pg_hba.conf`? `pg_ctl` is for doing start/stop/init operations on a server cluster. `pg_hba.conf` is a text file for setting up client authorization. You can access it with any text editor.  2) Have you confirmed via normal file operatiins that the path `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data` actually exists?